# Execute Batch file via Addin [VS]

Tags: c#, .net, batch-file, add-in

I am writing my first Visual Studio Addin with C# at the moment.
What I am trying to accomplish is to execute a batch file after a successfull build of a project or a solution.
The batch file is in the Folder "AdditionalDependecys" that is in the project folder of the Addin and the name of the file is "MakeInstall.bat".
I am trying to call it this way:

```
 private void OnBuildDone(vsBuildScope scope, vsBuildAction action)
    {
        ...
        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = @"makeInstall.bat",
            WorkingDirectory = "AdditionalDependencys",
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal,
            Arguments = fullpath + " " + projektName
        };

        System.Diagnostics.Process pr = new System.Diagnostics.Process { StartInfo = psi };
        pr.Start();
    }
```

This is throwing me an error that the file could not be found.
I guess this is happening because of the internal structure of the vs addins? Is it even possible to accomplish what I want with an Addin?

Thanks for your help an best regards

Comment: Allright I did it with the SatelliteDllPath now!
If I pass this to the process  it´ll work!
If there´s a better solution let me know :)